# 2d array addition in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, 2d

i am trying to add two 2D arrays in C++ with my following code by i am getting output as this
333 333, but i want out as 2 rows

```
    { 
        int a[2][3], b[2][3], i , j;

        cout<<"First Matrix"<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
    cin>>a[i] [j];
        }
    }
    cout<<"Second Matrix"<<endl;
            for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
        cin>>b[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            cout<<a[i] [j] + b[i] [j];
        }
        cout<<"    ";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    _getch();
    }
```

Comment: Every time to print the output, you need to tell the compiler that it is done executing one line and therefore needs to move to the next line. This will avoid over writing on the same line. So you just add <<endl; like cout<<a[i][j] + b[i][j]<<endl;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last `for` loop is wrong. You have to move `cout`'s.

```
for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            cout<<a[i] [j] + b[i] [j];
            cout<<"    ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
```

Also your variables `i` and `j` are unused because you are declaring new ones in `for` loops with `int i=0;` and `int j=0;`.

Answer (score 1):

How about changing the line that prints spaces to print a newline?

```
cout<<"    ";
```

becomes

```
cout<<"\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't put any newlines in your code, so of course it won't print out on a new line. replace `cout<<"    ";` with `cout<<std::endl;` and you should get each row on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last piece of code by this:

```
for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
        cout<<a[i] [j] + b[i] [j] << ' ';
    }
    cout<< "\n";
}
cout << "\n";
```